# IIS 8 and ARR with multiple other servers

Tags: iis, teamcity, url-rewrite-module, arr, youtrack

I am trying to setup IIS 8 with ARR and Url rewrite 2 module to work with two other servers (running Youtrack and TeamCity) and it just dont work...

Lets say my server have following URL: server.test.domain.com (i have no control about this part) so i want to 3 web sites:

```
server.test.domain.com -> default web site in IIS (classic web)
server.test.domain.com/youtrack -> Catalina with Youtrack
server.test.domain.com/teamcity -> Catalina with TeamCity
```

on server when i look on *localhost:81* i have working Youtrack and on *localhost:82 i* have TeamCity also workin OK.

I followed this tutorial: http://blogs.endjin.com/2010/11/a-step-by-step-guide-to-hosting-teamcity-in-iis-7/

but in last part he url rewrite it on some domain name and i dont know what URL rewrite RULE i have to use to make it work my way.

Comment: Try this approach: http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/reverse-proxy-with-url-rewrite-v2-and-application-request-routing

Comment: Ok so the trick was with this rewriteRule : ^(.*)/youtrack/(.*), Thanks man you really helped me. Only i have to rewrite to localhost:81/{R:2} then.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so the trick was with this rewriteRule : `^(.*)/youtrack/(.*)`, Thanks man you really helped me. Only i have to rewrite to localhost:81/{R:2} then. Also as Malvin said there is a par wher you have to enable Application request routing in hidden menu and that was whole trick.

Comment: Can you please provide your complete configuration? I created a Server Farm like in the tutorial, then opened the inbound rule and created a `{HTTP_HOST}` condition with `^(.*)/youtrack/(.*)` as pattern. When I then browse to `test.domain.com/youtrack` I just get `404 - File or directory not found`. Thanks.